Flutter background services is not running as expected
I have a a flutter that is build using flutterflow app that am tryin to run a service in background in it ..this services should be running a function every 3 minutes ..
here is my current code :
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:io'; // For platform-specific checks
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

late Function doableAction;

Future mainAction(Future Function() theAction) async {
  doableAction = theAction;
  await initializeService();
}

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'your_notification_channel_id', // id
      'Your Notification Channel', // title
      importance: Importance.high,
    );

    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  // Configure and start the service
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      isForegroundMode: true, // Ensure it runs as a foreground service
      notificationChannelId: 'your_notification_channel_id',
      initialNotificationTitle: 'Azan Notify',
      initialNotificationContent: 'Azan notify is running in background',
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      onForeground: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
    ),
  );

  // Start the service
  service.startService();

  // Execute the custom action once after service initialization
  await doTheAction();
}

// This function will run the background task
Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });

    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
    });

    service.on('onTaskRemoved').listen((event) {
      service.stopSelf();
    });
  }

  // Run the action repeatedly in a loop
  while (true) {
    // Removed the `isRunning` check
    print('Running doTheAction in background...');
    await doTheAction();

    // Wait for 3 minutes before repeating the action
    await Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 3));
  }
}

Future<void> doTheAction() async {
  try {
    print('Executing doableAction...');
    await doableAction(); // Ensure this is an async function
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error in doTheAction: $e');
  }
}

my action doableAction is playing an audio file from app assets .. and this is how the result goes:
1- when open the app and reach the page where i call mainActoin function ..the audio file plays as expected ..and never runs again even if i kept the app in foreground.
2- when i take the app to the background ..i see the notification ..but the audio files never plays again ..

1.Assign permission for both platform(Android & iOS),
AndroidManifest.xml
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
        
         <application>
             <service android:name="com.example.projectName"
               android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
                android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data 
          android:name="flutterEmbedding"
          android:value="2"/>
     </application>
 </manifest>  

any error in android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync", just replace it with with
android:foregroundServiceType="location"

info.plist
<array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>location</string>
</array>

your remaining code
